# Corrupt Word Document on Second Download

Tags: javascript, ms-word, docx

I have a question for a confidential project that I am working on, so I cannot share too much detail. Hopefully the below code is enough to at least provide some suggestions as to what can be wrong.

Whenever I programmatically download a word blob from an anchor link, it fails on the second try only saying that it could not open the file as it is corrupt. I also see that the file is about 14KB larger.

```
// route file
var buffer = await Packer.toBuffer(doc); // create buffer using DOCX.js Packer
res.header(
  "output_name",
  `${unique_output_str}.docx` // <--- this is a template string which changes each time the document is generated, based on unique attributes that the user selects
);
res.send(Buffer.from(buffer));
```

How I download:

```
var response = await axios.patch(
  path, // <--- this is defined elsewhere (not relevant to question)
  formData, // <--- this is defined elsewhere (not relevant to question)
  { responseType: "blob" }
);

const url = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([response.data], {
    type:
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  })
);

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = url;
link.download = response.headers["output_name"];
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

How come my first download after form submission produces a good docx file, but resubmitting the form with other data (changes in text for text input) produces corrupt files?

Comment: The issue would most likely be on the server side - perhaps in the process of creating the value in `doc` - which you have not shown

Comment: @JaromandaX Good to know, after testing many different aspects of my code I came to the same conclusion but just wanted to double check if the client side is acceptable. Unfortunately, I cannot share the `doc` creating code as it contains sensitive information. The part that confuses me is why it works (not corrupt) the first time I submit the form, but fails in consecutive attempts.

Comment: Write a version of the code that you can share. You may actually identify and solve your issue through that process.